# Type elements of a list more efficiently

Tags: r

In many situations I will need to type the same list name several times in order to specify every elements in the list. For example, say I have a list called `BIGLIST` which contains 6 plots. Now, I want to put these plots together, the following codes is what I will do.

```
cowplot::plot_grid(BIGLIST[[1]],BIGLIST[[2]],BIGLIST[[3]],BIGLIST[[4]],BIGLIST[[5]],BIGLIST[[6]],nrow=6)
```

I was trying some approaches to simplify this process. For example,

```
cowplot::plot_grid(rep(paste0('BIGLIST','[[',1:6,']]',sep=',')),nrow=6)
```

But this is not worked as now `BIGLIST` becomes a character.

Are there any methods I can save copy-paste in such situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `plotlist` argument of `plot_grid`.

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = BIGLIST, nrow = length(BIGLIST))
```